# Cannot connect to an EC2 instance, with http request, within vpc (with EIP)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc, eip

i opened elasticsearch server (logs server) on one of my ec2 instances within a vpc in AWS. I gave the instance an EIP (elastic ip).

the server listen on port 9200. and as you know (or not) an EC2 instance has a private ip (i.e 10.0.0.84).

So if i go to another instance that in the same vpc as the log server, and write in the browser 10.0.0.84:9200 i get an answer, but if i write in the browser from my home (or from an instance that in the same vpc) the line eip:9200 i got no response.

i checked it and there are no problems with the ACL Network and Security Groups (all ports are open).

as i know an ec2 instance doesn't know his eip (it doesn't appear when i write the cmd "ipconfig /all").

am i missing something? i think i don't understand the architecture..

Answer (score 0):

Your subnet's Route table should have record like

0.0.0.0/0 igw

With attached Internet Gateway assigned to this subnet. 
More docs here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html